# Find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, if $1-\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 \geq \sec^2 p$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a problem that I have not been able to solve. I don't know how to approach differential equations when used in intervals ...

> Find $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, if 
>   $$1-\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 \geq \sec^2 p$$ 
>   for $p\in \operatorname{dom}(\sec x)$.

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJTZj.png)

Comment: In what relation are the variables apart from the one written? Loosely interpreted, this inequality is impossible, as the right side can be arbitrarily large, larger than $1$ easily.

Comment: Assuming p is fixed, the inequality is 1 - sec$^2$ p >= y'$^2.$  That forces y'$^2$ = 0.  Thus y" = ...

Answer (score 1):

Following William Elliot's comment above, given $p\in\mathbb{R}$ fixed and abbreviating $\frac{dy}{dx}=y'$ we have
$$1-\sec^2 p = 1- \frac{1}{\cos^2(p)} \geq y'^2.$$ Because $0 \leq \cos(p)^2 \leq 1$, we have $\frac{1}{\cos^2(p)}=\sec^ 2 p \geq 1$ and thus $$1-\sec^2 p\leq 0.$$ As $y'^2\geq 0$, the original inequality implies $y'(x)=0$ (for whatever values of $x$ the original inequality is supposed to hold). In particular, if  $y'(x)=0$ for all $x$, we find
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}(x)= \frac{d}{dx}y'(x)=0$$ for all $x$.